# Rename files with names from a list in python

Tags: python

I have a bunch of files that I got into python with :

```
def list_files(path):
    # returns a list of names (with extension, without full path) of all files 
    # in folder path
    files = []
    for name in os.listdir(path):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, name)):
            files.append(name)
    return files 

images = list_files('.')

>>> images
['file1.jpg', 'file2.jpg', 'file3.jpg']
```

I also have a list like :

```
>>> b
['ren', 'sans', 'ren']
```

I wan't to rename images and append the corresponding strings in b, so to get :

file1-ren.jpg
file2-sans.jpg
file3-ren.jpg

```
for imgs in images :
    os.rename(imgs,''.join(imgs + b for f in b))

TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'numpy.ndarray' objects
```

Am I thinking this alright ?
Thanks

Comment: how does ren/sans/ren turn into ren/ren/ren?

Comment: Did you want `imgs + f` rather than `imgs + b` in your `join`?

Comment: Also note that `os.listdir` doesn't specify any particular order for the names that it returns . . .

Comment: sorry for the typo ren/sans/ren

Comment: os.listdir returns the files in the exact same order than 'ls' would have. So I guess this is what the OP and most shell scripts also would expect.

Comment: The order is not an issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea would be more like:

```
for img, extra in zip(images, b) :
    os.rename(img, ''.join([img, '-', extra, '.jpg'])
```

However, it means that you have already removed the extension from img.

If not, then:

```
for img, extra in zip(images, b) :
    filename, extension = os.path.splitext(img)
    os.rename(img, ''.join([filename, '-', extra, extension])
```

Comment: But, this works, in this case, because len(b) == len(images) otherwise it wouldn't of course.